# Loop through array of Date Objects and compare which one is latest and earliest

Tags: javascript, loops, date

If I have this structure:

```
 const datesList = [2022-07-15T19:41:12.620Z, 2022-07-20T11:21:52.596Z, 2022-07-13T11:21:50.596Z]
```

How can I loop through it and find out which one is the later and the earlier date?

I've tried using forEach loop and its not working..

Comment: What do you mean by comparing? Sorting?

Comment: Please post the code that is "not working"; there might be a way to fix it.

Comment: "I've tried using forEach loop and its not working.." Show what you did

Answer (score 0):

You can compare using getTime() which gets the time in ms since 1970

```js
var dateList = [new Date(Date.parse("2022-07-15T19:41:12.620Z")), new Date(), new Date(+5), new Date(1236876666273)]

console.log(dateList.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.getTime() < b.getTime()) {
    return -1
  }
  if (a.getTime() > b.getTime()) {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}))
```

Comment: what if i have more than two dates in my array?

Comment: It will sort them. I'll update my example

Answer (score 0):

- `Date.parse()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC of string input for valie date.
- I just used `dort` function of es6.

```js
const datesList = ["2022-07-15T19:41:12.620Z", "2022-07-20T11:21:52.596Z", "2022-07-13T11:21:50.596Z"];
console.log(datesList.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b)));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get each string date, abd parse them into timestamp numbers

   ```
   .map(d => Date.parse(d))
   ```
2. Sort the array of timestamp numbers

   ```
   .sort((a, b) => a - b)
   ```
3. Convert the numbers into date strings

   ```
   .map(t => new Date(t));
   ```

```js
const dates = ['2022-07-15T19:41:12.620Z', '2022-07-20T11:21:52.596Z', '2022-07-13T11:21:50.596Z'];
 
 let output = dates
 .map(d => Date.parse(d))
 .sort((a, b) => a - b)
 .map(t => new Date(t));
 
console.log(output);
```

Comment: why would i transform it into string if they are already date objects?

Comment: True, I was actually in midstride onto another path and forgot to change that, thanks for reminding me, I've updated it.